# .sks in singleViewApplication. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, app

У меня есть простая программа в Xcode. Я создал файл .sks с текстурой rain.
Как я могу подключить данный файл в свой проект, если это не проект Game, а просто singleView

Я подключил сцену, все работает. Но вместо дождя у меня квадратики с крестиком внутри..

Answer (score 0):

Скопируйте файл `sks` в проект, для его рендеринга добавьте вью с классом `SKView` и необходимый код, где нужно добавьте `import SpriteKit` и `import GameplayKit`, в целом шаблон Game ничем не отличается от обычного

Comment: Я обновил свой вопрос.

Answer (score -1):

Мне помог следующий код, где я указал нод.

```
   class Scene: SKScene
    {
        override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
           self.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            let node = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Fire")!
            node.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height)
            self.addChild(node)
        }

}
```